# finding an element by ID in javascript

Tags: javascript

There are a paragraph containing an anchor tag, and I want to get Element using id in javascript:

```
<p>Please visit <a id="myblog" href="/myblog/"> My Blog </a></p>
```

I used the code below in .js file to get a tag:

```
var target = document.getElementById("myblog");
```

and in result target is empty? why?

Comment: Could it be that you call getElementById prior to the DOM being ready? Move the code to the end of your body-element and it should work fine.

Comment: Instead of littering the body tag with scripts you can keep them either as usualy in just the head tag or a separate js file if possible and use `window.onload` instead. If you have multiple functions you want to add you can also use `window.addEventListener('load', function () {})` It will keep your DOM clean and enables you to keep your JavaScript unobtrusive.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely explanation is that your script is being run before the element in question has been added to the page.

The simplest solution is to put your scripts right at the end of the page, before the `</body>` tag.